# parse multiline tab separated Json in python

Tags: python, json

{JSON-1}    {JSON-2}
{JSON-1}    {JSON-2}
{JSON-1}    {JSON-2}

Json is multilines and tab separated also as above. Only JSON-2 is of use. 
How to parse this type of json in python?

Comment: *Only JSON-2 is of use* - and what is `{JSON-1}` ?

Comment: That's not a valid JSON file, so you will have to parse it manually. If there are no tabs inside any of the objects you might get away with splitting rows and parsing each part separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start out by ignoring the fact that the data is JSON at all.

- Open the file
- Iterate each line in the file using `for line in f`
- Split the two tab-separated fields using `line.split('\t')`
- *Then* convert the portion of interest into a Python object using `json.loads()`

Example:

```
import json

with open('weird_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        json1, json2 = line.split('\t')
        j2 = json.loads(json2)

        # Use j2
```

Comment: I like your solution. :-)

Comment: @AlexL Hey, yours too. I beat you by 8 seconds :-)

Comment: Thanks @JonathonReinhart!

This illustrates one of the things that's awesome about python: wide consensus about the best/simplest/most obvious ways to do things. A huge boon for folks writing, and especially reading, python. It's the opposite of the perl mantra, "There's More Than One Way To Do It", which also applies to Ruby...

Comment: (I guess I need to learn how to @mention people on StackOverflow...sigh...)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to fill in the details and make some adjustments, but something like this should do the trick. The key is that you can split each line on the tab, and then use `json.loads` to parse just the part that you want.

```
import json

with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        j1, j2 = line.split('\t')
        decoded = json.loads(j2)
```